# Manage Outlook programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I need to perform the same task on all items in Outlook 2007's Tasks section.

Before doing this with AutoIT, I wanted to check if the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook (COM DLL?) is the way to go with VB.Net, or if there are better options?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, [**Office PIA**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) is the way to go if you want to use VB.NET to integrate with Outlook. Another alternative would be using [**EWS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a stand-alone Outlook, ie. without an Exchanger server. I'll check out Office PIA. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Visual Studio Tools for Office from Microsoft.